# Query to Show only when a number of rows meet a certain condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table where i store appointments for customers, there are multiple apointments that span through multiple weeks, the customers may or may not complete all the apointments.

Let's say someting like this:

```
apointment_order(PrimaryKey) 
Line(PrimaryKey) 
Customer_id 
Date  
Apointment_Type   
Apointment_Status
```

I have 4 different appointment types(**1st session, 2nd session...**) 
and two status (**Completed, Not Completed**)

I need help designing a query that only gets me the appointments_order where
all the appointment types in that order are of Completed Status.

For instance if an appointment order has 4 Appointment types and only 3 are of completed status then it shouldn't appear in the result.

My objective is to know all the customers that completed all the sessions(1-4).

Comment: What you have tried please add here?

Comment: I have tried something like this. `Select * From AppointmentsTable WHERE Apointment_Type IN ('1stSession','2ndSession','3rdSession','4thSession') AND Apointment_status = 'Completed'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, using `group by` and `having`:

```
select a.apointment_order
from appointments a
group by a.apointment_order
having count(a.Apointment_Type = 'Completed') = count(*);
```